# Should function composition and piping be tested?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, functional-programming, fscheck

In F# (and most of the functional languages) some codes are extremely short as follows:

```
let f = getNames
>> Observable.flatmap ObservableJson.jsonArrayToObservableObjects<string>
```

or :

```
let jsonArrayToObservableObjects<'t> =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'t[]> 
    >> Observable.ToObservable
```

And the simplest property-based test I ended up for the latter function is :

```
 testList "ObservableJson" [
        testProperty "Should convert an Observable of `json` array to Observable of single F# objects" <| fun _ -> 
            //--Arrange--
            let (array , json) = createAJsonArrayOfString stringArray

            //--Act--
            let actual = jsonArray
                         |> ObservableJson.jsonArrayToObservableObjects<string> 
                         |> Observable.ToArray 
                         |> Observable.Wait


            //--Assert--
            Expect.sequenceEqual actual sArray
    ]
```

Regardless of the arrange part, the test is more than the function under test, so it's harder to read than the function under test!

- What would be the value of testing when it's harder to read than the production code?

On the other hand:

- I wonder whether the functions which are a composition of multiple functions are safe to not to be tested?
- Should they be tested at integration and acceptance level?
- And what if they are short but do complex operations?

Comment: This question is primarily about the development process, coding style, and software design, not about a particular f# code. So I guess it would better fit at [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: @bytebuster: But i'm implementing it by F#.

Comment: Would the C# (or any language) implementation have different ratio for code / test in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon your definition of what 'functional programming' is. Or even more precise - upon how close you wanna stay to the origin of functional programming - math with both broad and narrow meanings.

Let's take something relevant to the programming. Say, mappings theory. Your question could be translated in such a way: having a bijection from A to B, and a bijection from B to C, should I prove that composition of those two is a bijection as well? The answer is twofold: you definitely should, and you do it only once: your prove is generic enough to cover all possible cases.

Falling back into programming, it means that pipe-lining has to be tested (proved) only once - and I guess it was before deploy to the production. Since that your job as a programmer to create functions (mappings) of such a quality, that, being composed with a pipeline operator or whatever else, **the desired properties are preserved**. Once again, it's better to stick with generic arguments rather than write tons of similar tests.

So, finally, we come down to a much more valuable question: how one can guarantee that some operation preserve some property? It turns out that the easiest way to acknowledge such a fact is to deal with types like `Monoid` from the great Haskell: for example, `Monoind` is there to represent any **associative** binary operation `A -> A -> A` together with some identity-element of type `A`. Having such a generic containers is extremely profitable and the best known way of being explicit in what and how exactly your code is designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would NOT test it.

In fact having less need for testing and instead relying more on stricter compiler rules, side effect free functions, immutability etc. is one major reason why I prefer F# over C#.

of course I continue (unit)testing of "custom logic" ... e.g. algorithmic code